# Dynamically create Array of Type in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, types

I want to consume an Object and create an Array of that specific Type.

Example:

```
Class oClass = o.getClass().getComponentType();
oClass[] newArray = new oClass[10];
// or alternately
ArrayList<oClass> newArray = new ArrayList<oClass>();
```

Comment: What do you plan to do after that? You can create the array using `Array.newInstance`, but you're not going to have strongly-typed access to it. Please provide more context.

Comment: I'm trying to implement my own array/arraylist-like Class, which is more suitable to my needs. I want to later be able to initialize it like a regular Array (new myArray(String) or new myArray(Integer) ). Obviously I shouldn't be able to later add Objects of different types to the array.

Comment: So what would you expect the `add` method to look like? Basically, you should try to think beyond just this first part - put together a more complete picture. I think you'll find there are more problems than just the creation part.

Comment: Can't I just initialize my Class with a certain Type and have it only accept that type? Do I need to use generics for that?

Comment: You can get it to check that at execution time, yes - but not at compile-time, because you won't know the type at compile-time. Again, you should think about the bigger picture about what kind of safety you're expecting, how you're expecting to be used it etc.

Comment: how would I be able to accomplish this at execution time? I still need to save the type of my Array and have my add-method accept/reject correct/incorrect types.

Comment: Yes, so you remember the `Class<?>` passed into your constructor (or whatever), and use `Class.isInstance` on each `add` call.